# Finding patterns in strings using basic Java methods

Tags: java, string, character

say we have a string with these characters
    "ABGCCFFGTBG"

then we have another string with characters     "GECCCDOABG"

So the pattern is the prefix and suffix but if your given strings larger then this but have common prefix and suffix patterns how to pull those out into a substring in java. Keep in mind we dont always know the characters in the string were getting we just know there is a pattern in it.

my start is something like this

```
for(int i = 0. i < strA.length(); i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < strB.length(); j++)
    {
       if(strA.charAt(i) == strB.charAt(j))
       {
          String subPattern = strA.substring(0,i);
          String subPattern2 = strB.substring(0,j);
       }
    }
}
```

but this doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: an example is pulling out the ABG in the string because its in both as a pattern into a substring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to select best-matched pattern at first:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String strA = "ABGCCFFGTBG";
    String strB = "GECCCDOABG";
    System.out.println("Pattern: " + findPattern(strA, strB));
}

public static String findPattern(String strA, String strB) {
    for (int length = Math.min(strA.length(), strB.length()); length > 0; length--) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= strA.length() - length; i++) {
            String pattern = strA.substring(i, i + length);
            if (strB.contains(pattern)) {
                return pattern;
            }
        }
    }
    throw new NoSuchElementException("No common pattern between " + strA + " and " + strB);
}
```

Output:

```
Pattern: ABG
```

Comment: the only issue is i need to get values like how ABG are common pattern in both but this implementation only gives me C

Comment: Use return instead of println and you'll get the best match value.

Comment: how? its not value returning

Comment: Is it a joke? just modify this code into your own method with arguments (String strA, String strB) and return type String.

Comment: it does work but only using one return gives me the value B I still need ABG. Only one return statement allowed

Comment: input : `String strA = "ABGCCFFGTBG";
    String strB = "ABGCCFFGTBG";` ourput : `ABGCCFFGTB` which is not correct

Answer (score 0):

this solution will find a pattern, no matter where it is in the string:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String strA = "uioABCDqwert";
    String strB = "yxcvABCDwrk";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < strA.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < strB.length(); j++) {
            if (strA.charAt(i) == strB.charAt(j)) {
                sb.append(strB.charAt(j));
                i++;
            }
        }
        if (sb.length() > 0)
            break;
    }

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

this should give you an idea how it could be done

Comment: what if its a value returning method like String or if you cant use break statement?